# Merge two Streams (ordered) to get a final sorted Stream

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation, tail-recursion

For example, how to merge two Streams of sorted Integers? I thought it's very basic, but just found it's non trivial at all. The below one is not tail-recursive and it will stack-overflow when the Streams are large.

```
def merge(as: Stream[Int], bs: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
  (as, bs) match {
    case (Stream.Empty, bss) => bss
    case (ass, Stream.Empty) => ass
    case (a #:: ass, b #:: bss) =>
      if (a < b) a #:: merge(ass, bs)
      else b #:: merge(as, bss)
  }
}
```

We may want to turn it into a tail-recursive one by introducing a accumulator. However, if we pre-pend the accumulator, we will only get a stream of reversed order; if we append the accumulator with concatenation (#:::), it's NOT lazy (strict) any more.

What could be the solution here? Thanks

Comment: "The below one is not tail-recursive and it will stack-overflow when the Streams are large." Why? The recursion isn't "real" in that the merge  in the "recursive" call shouldn't be evaluated yet.  That is, your code isn't recursive at all since it returns a new stream from either branch of the `if`?  Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 7):

Turning a comment into an answer, there's nothing wrong with your merge.

It's not recursive at all - any one call to merge returns a new Stream without any other call to merge. `a #:: merge(ass, bs)` return a stream with first element `a` and where `merge(ass, bs)` will be called to evaluate the rest of the stream when required.

So

```
val m = merge(Stream.from(1,2), Stream.from(2, 2))
//> m  : Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
m.drop(10000000).take(1)
//> res0:     scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(10000001, ?)
```

works just fine. No stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that since it's not tail-recursive, your above sample code will OOM since the stack frame will hold a reference to the stream's head I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct (but I've not tested it). Once you access the next element in the stream the previous stack frame/closure will be unreferenced and be GC;'d, I think.